# Не находит числа в файле

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]С помощью регулярных выражений найти в тексте все даты. Даты записаны в европейском формате (день-месяц-год)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace _6._1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            string dataFromFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Malson\Desktop\1.txt");
            
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\d{1,2}([-. /])\d{1,2}\1\d{2,4}$");

            MatchCollection roj = reg.Matches(dataFromFile);

            if (roj.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Match match in roj)
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Совпадений не найдено");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С такой регуляркой могут находиться невалидные даты, если что

Comment: Даты записаны в формате csv, через new line, или как?

Comment: У вас же `^` и `$` внутри регулярки!

Comment: Покажите исходные данные и результат вывода, результаты отладки, хоть что-нибудь.

Comment: добавил исходник и вывод в консоль

Comment: Минус за белую и черную простыни. Если постишь скриншоты, то хотя бы приведи их в приличный вид.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Я так и не понял, в чём проблема. Регулярка нормальная, если невалидные даты тоже подходят https://regexr.com/5aqag

Answer (score 1):

```
new Regex(@"^\d{1,2}([-. /])\d{1,2}\1\d{2,4}(?=\r?$)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Параметр [RegexOptions.Multiline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netcore-3.1) нужен для того, чтобы символы `^` и `$` работали для каждой *строки*, а не для всего *текста*.

[Якорь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#anchors) `$` находит совпадение в конце строки или перед символом `\n`. А в тексте наверняка содержатся последовательности `\r\n`. Поэтому нужно добавить поиск `\r` (необязательный). И чтобы сам этот символ не захватывался, используем [просмотр вперёд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4).